# unable to use GPIO, UART, SPI etc in Freertos in Intel Galieo Gen 2

Tags: intel, freertos, microprocessors, galileo, intel-galileo

I am newbie in Freertos. I have just started working on Freertos, so forgive me if my question is silly. I have got Intel Galileo Gen 2 board, in which I successfully run a demo application of Freertos. [Link for the tutorial is here](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS_Intel_Quark_Galileo_GCC.html).
Now I tried to make my own application. For this I study some Freertos tutorials. [Link for the tutorial is here.](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Starting_with_FreeRTOS). After reading this tutorial I have learned basics of Freertos but I can't figure out how to use use GPIO, UART, SPI etc of my board. There is nothing available on internet regarding my problem. Is there any library available which I can use for my GPIO, UART, SPI etc in Freertos in Intel Galelio Gen2 or there any other approach to use GPIO, UART, SPI etc?

Comment: First question, why not Zephyr RTOS? The other one, are you sure that OS has necessary drivers?